# Android: how to dispaly the same video preview in different processes

Tags: android, preview

In android, one activity displays a preview(video).And I hope this preview will still be displayed in another activity, when  this activity switches to another. How to do?

**My Initial ideas:**using a remote service manage the only control mediaplayer, then different processes can access this mediaplayer using IPC. but I don't know how to transfer a mediaplayer from service to client. Any one can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> In android, one activity displays a preview(video).And I hope this preview will still be displayed in another activity, when this activity switches to another. How to do?

Simple: merge the two activities into one, so you do not switch activities.

> using a remote service manage the only control mediaplayer, then different processes can access this mediaplayer using IPC. but I don't know how to transfer a mediaplayer from service to client.

That is impossible.